# Input processing in Java

Tags: java, input

I am trying write a program in Java which involves getting the number of characters from a strıng and if the number of characters is between 6-10  and if there is an upper case, a lower case, a vowel it will print password is usable if not it will print ypu cannot use this password.

Comment: If you're a newbie then this is good practise to figure out yourself. At least make some attempts, and show your code if you get stuck on something.

Answer (score 1):

This program reads input from the console. For each line of input, it will check if all the mentioned criteria matches and prints whether its usable or not.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PasswordValidator{
  private static final ArrayList<Character> vowels = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'));

  private static boolean isCorrectLength(String password){
    int passwordLen = password.length();
    if(passwordLen >= 6 && passwordLen <= 10)
      return true;
    return false;
  }

  private static boolean containsVowel(String password){
    for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
      if(vowels.contains(password.charAt(i))){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  private static boolean containsLowerCase(String password){
    for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
      if(password.charAt(i) == Character.toLowerCase(password.charAt(i))){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  private static boolean containsUpperCase(String password){
    for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
      if(password.charAt(i) == Character.toUpperCase(password.charAt(i))){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
      String result = sc.nextLine();
      if(containsUpperCase(result) && containsLowerCase(result) &&
       containsVowel(result) && isCorrectLength(result))
        System.out.printf("This is a usable password\n");
      else
        System.out.printf("You cannot use this password\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    String p = "PassWord";
    System.out.println(p.length() >= 6 && p.length() <= 10
            && p.matches(".*[a-z].*") && p.matches(".*[A-Z].*")
            && p.matches(".*[aeiouAEIOU].*")
            ? "password is usable" : "ypu cannot use this password");
```